# SEF urls in application

Tags: php, sef

I have an application and would like to write a function to convert my links to SEF version if mod_rewrite enabled.

Example of my URL:

```
index.php?url=products/index;
index.php?url=products/id/3;
```

So I need something like this:

```
Route::get('index.php?url=products/index');
```

Return me **products/index** if .htaccess in the folder (SEF enabled) or **index.php?url=products/index** if not.

Comment: What's your question?  Is `Route::get` part of a framework you are using?  Are you trying to rewrite `products/index` to `index.php?url=products/index`?

Comment: No I need this function to write.